# Room synchronization : How to ensure multiple threads are using same node?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, synchronization

(Problem link to wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_synchronization)

Suppose there are N resources of type NODE, represented by an array

```
 NODE  nodearray[N];
```

Lets say there are M threads which act (read/write).
When the first thread arrives, it has liberty to choose from any of the N resource, but as long as first thread is holding on to resource number x (x is 0 to n-1), the second thread MUST use the same x.

Say we are to implement two functions

```
int get();// gets the resource number for the thread and 
void ret();// returns the resource from the thread
```

Any idea/hint how it could be implemented ?

Comment: I am not clear on your requirement. If i go by your logic then at a time only one resource will be used, even if 100 threads try to work simultaneously. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Lokesh  : Yes : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_synchronization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem as you've stated it, I don't think you need to keep anything more than a single counter, an indication of which (single) resource is currently in use, and a mutex to make all of your function calls atomic.

(**Edit**: I originally had code in here but it was almost identical to the code @Ajeet posted in his answer to his own question several hours before I posted this.  So look at @Ajeet's answer if you want the code in C.)

The form of room synchronization you proposed is not what the original authors had in mind [(link to pdf)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~blelloch/papers/BCG03.pdf).  They needed an operation where the caller specifies what room they want to get into.  The caller needs to *wait* if someone else is in a different room.  So in that case we have:

```
void enter(int roomnum);  // wait until everyone is out of all rooms other than roomnum
void exit(int roomnum);   // exit roomnum
```

And the implementation is more interesting.  (Hint: in addition to the three variables above you also need a condition variable.)

If you are wondering why any of this is the least bit useful (I was wondering that): in the paper I linked to they are trying to implement relatively complicated scalable concurrent algorithms.  They present a way to solve the room synchronization problem using ticket spin locks (page 7).  And show how to use the room synchronization problem to implement a scalable concurrent stack (page 4).  (The insight for the concurrent stack is: it is okay for an arbitrary number of threads to simultaneously push using fetch-and-increment, and it is okay for an arbitrary number of threads to simultaneously pop using fetch-and-decrement, but you need to make sure there are no pushes and pops happening simultaneously.)

Comment: Thanks for info on where the room-synchronization could be used and the original use-case for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solutions but would be great if someone can critique it.

```
int counter = 0;
int current = -1;
NODE  nodearray[N];
mutex m;

int get() {
  lock(m);
  if(!counter) {
    current = rand()%N;
  }
  ++counter;
  unlock(m);
  return current;
}

void ret() {
  lock(m);
  --counter;
  if(!counter) {
    current = -1;
  }
  unlock(m);
}
```

Comment: why do u need counter? just check the value of current that should be sufficient

Comment: @Lokesh :  Suppose two threads have called ret(), how would program know about resetting of of current ? 
Think of counter as a reference-counting variable.

Comment: @Ajeet: I came up with an almost identical implementation.  I will edit my post to remove my implementation and point to yours.

Answer (score 0):

If i were to implement this. I would create a wrapper on top of all resources available. Your scenario is like a resource pool of size 1.

Resource pool instance would be static and get and ret methods would be defined in it. This resource pool implementation will pick one resource when get is called and will keep track if resource is being used. If it is being used then same instance will always be returned. If it is not being used then you can release the resource [you can even put a timeout before releasing a resource].

Internal resource pool implementation can vary based of choice of classes like synchronizers, concurrent hashmaps etc.